# "42883: operator does not exist: interval - timestamp without time zone" in POSTGRES

Tags: postgresql, netezza

I have created one table and inserting one record with below two queries.

```
create table tt1(c1 timestamp);
insert into tt1(c1) values('1903-11-05 17:45:36');
```

After that, I'm trying to run below select query

```
select '1980-12-23 00:30' - c1 - c1 from tt1;
```

Getting below error.

> 42883: operator does not exist: interval - timestamp without time zone

Comment: Netezza and Postgres are two very different database products. Which one are you really using?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with that SELECT statement? That doesn't really make sense to me. `'1980-12-23 00:30' - c1` yields an `interval` and - as the error message tells you, you can't subtract a timestamp from an interval,  what do you expect from `78 years 3 mons 2 days 6 hours 44 mins - '1903-11-05 17:45:36'`?

Comment: That's still the same thing. Subtracting a timestamp from a timestamp (`c1 - '1980-12-23 00:30' `)  yields an interval and you can't subtract a timestamp from that result.

Comment: Yes obviously. And I have explained twice why you get the error. You should take a step back and explain what the actual, underlying problem is you want to solve. What is the output you are after? The statement as shown simply doesn't make sense.